# Parameter for column / table names in SQL query in Pentaho CDE dashboard

Tags: jdbc, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to use parameters for column and table name to SQL query over JNDY, which doesn't work, while parameters for values work fine.

I defined 3 simple parameter components with default values:

```
paramTable = 'dummyTable'
paramColumn = 'dummyColumn'
paramValue = 'dummyValue'
```

Then I defined an SQL query over JNDI, that looks like:

```
select * from ${paramTable} where ${paramColumn} = ${paramValue};
```

... which does not work, because parameter values of paramTable and paramColumn don't seem to apply properly, which causes:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Here are some query modifications, and their results really disappoint me:

```
select * from dummyTable where dummyColumn = ${paramValue}; 
-- works fine and delivers 1 row

select * from ${paramTable} where dummyColumn = 'dummyValue'; 
-- causes 'invalid table name' 

select * from dummyTable where ${paramColumn} = 'dummyValue'; 
-- does not cause any errors, but if I console.log() the result set of the query, 
   it is empty (1 row is expected though)
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: JDBC drivers don't accept just about anything as parameters. In particular, object names cannot be parametrized.

Comment: Thank you nsousa, I see now.